# How will thread2, waiting on a condition, wake, when signalled from thread1, while mutex(common) is still locked by thread1?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

Suppose our threads look something like this:

thread1:

```
Lock(mutex) {
    //code
    if(something)
        signal(condition_var);
    //code
} //unlocks
```

thread2:

```
Lock(mutex) {
    //code
    while(something)
        wait(mutex, condition_var);
    //code
} //unlocks
```

1) Suppose the signal in thread1 gets executed and then context switch happens before mutex gets unlocked.

2) thread2 which was waiting on condition_var, attempts to continue but mutex is still locked. Now it will keep waiting i guess. Suppose context happens again.

3) thread1 now finishes and unlocks mutex.

How will wait in thread2 behave now, as anything won't signal it again, how will thread2 stop waiting?

Comment: Locked mutex doesn't prevent being awaken on conditional variable when someone calls `signal()`. In that case, instead of waiting on condition variable, thread begins to wait on mutex. This waiting ends when someone unlock mutex(at the step 3 in you example).

Comment: Yes, you are right. This was mentioned in spurious wake ups section of the videos lectures i am watching. I did'nt get it that time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the condition variable is signalled, the thread waiting on that condition variable will be put into a state where it is trying to re-acquire the mutex and then proceed.  It doesn't need to be signalled again after this - if the mutex is released eventually, it will proceed (it's now just like it's waiting in a normal attempt to lock the mutex).

Comment: Also generally not necessary to be holding a lock while signaling. That avoids waking the other thread just for it to block on acquiring the mutex.